# Oracle SQL Developer/Data Modeler Forward Engineering Logical to Relational Model, apply glossary?

Tags: sql, oracle, user-interface, documentation, modeling

I heard that the SQL Developer by Oracle can use a glossary to do the translation of the attribute/object names in the logical model to the names of the tables/columns in the relational model.

By default, when I create a logical model and then let the program "forward engineer" it to a relational model, it just replaces all spaces with underscores. However, I want it to apply a glossary file (which I created in the "create glossary from logical model window" and saved to an external file). This file spcifies abbreviations like "user" should be shortened to "USR" and "point" to "PT". I would also like it to capitalize all the words I did not specify an abbreviation for.

Does anyone have some experience with that program and could help me with this. I can't seem to find the steps for this in the documentation ( http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E39885_01/doc.40/e48205.pdf http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E39885_01/appdev.40/e38414.pdf ). Or do you suggest I go to the project directory (folder with db.dmd => db\rel\C9917379-2BE539524E71\table\seg_0) and mess with the xml files to do the translations myself?

Regards, Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a tutorial explaining what I wanted to do:

http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/sqldev/Glossaries/glossaries_viewlet_swf.html

on the download page under demonstrations "Working with Glossaries"

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnru

This was for version 3 (of the Data Modeler, which is part of the sql developer). In version 4, the "Preferences" window shown can be opened by right clicking on the top node in the Data Modeler > Browser view and going to properties (settings?).

This is also worth reading:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/datamodelernamingstandards-167685.pdf